# Laravel - send email with model observer on one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making an order submission feature for my eCommerce app in Laravel. For every order submission, I created an order record in my `orders` table. And them add items to `order_items` table pointing to the order I just created. My controller is as below:

```
DB::transaction(function () use ($customer, $request) {
        $order = Order::create([
            'order_number' => Order::createOrderNumber(),
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'note' => $request->input('note'),
            'status' => 'PENDING',
            'request_date' => $request->input('date'),
        ]);

        $parts = json_decode($request->input('parts'));
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            foreach ($part->selections as $selection) {
                $order_item = OrderItem::create([
                    'order_id' => $order->id,
                    'selection_id' => $selection->id,
                    'quantity' => $selection->quantity,
                    'price' => Selection::find($selection->id)->first()->price
                ]);
                if (isset($selection->file)) {
                    $file = $request->file('files')[$selection->file];
                    $filename_original = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $extension = $file->extension();
                    $filename = md5(microtime()).'.'.$extension;
                    try {
                        $file->storeAs('/files/order/'.$order->order_number, $filename);
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                    }
                    $order_item->filename = $filename;
                    $order_item->filename_original = $filename_original;
                    $order_item->save();
                }
            }
        }
```

This works all fine with order creation. Now I am trying to send a confirmation email containing all the order details when this is done. I can directly add the mailable to my controller and that would work all fine. But I am trying to separate all the "side effect" from controller by using a model observer. So I tried to send the email from `Order` observer, listening to the `created`

```
public function created(Order $order)
{
    Mail::to($order->customer->email)->send(new OrderMail($order, 'confirmation'));
}
```

Though email sent out, it terms out since my `Order` was created before adding all `items`, and the observer fire as soon as the model created, when I use relationship in my email view, it always return empty array

```
    @foreach($order->items as $item)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
        <td class="alignright">$ {{ number_format($item->subtotal, 2, '.', ',') }}</td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Is there any way that I can still separate my email sending process from controller, but will wait until my "adding item to order" process complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For segregating the email process, you can make use of Laravel Event/Listener system. For example, you can create event called `OrderSubmitted` and its listener called `SendEmailNotification`

For more info about Laravel event/listener system: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events

Comment: Just make sure, you fire the event (passing Order object) when its items have been processed (that is fire it in the end)